# Linux Extracting a rar format file

Tags: linux, rar

I copied a `.rar` file from a Windows to a Linux machine using WINSCP tool.
After copying the file, I tried to extract the `.rar` file, but I wasn't successful.

I tried using `unrar` and `file.rar`.

I got this error:

```
Unknown command on to putty console.
```

Please tell me how to extract the RAR file in the same directory.

Comment: Sounds like `unrar` isn't installed on the Linux machine. Can you install it?

Comment: I guess this questions belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have logged into the Linux machiene as a staff user , i dont know whether i can install it or not ?? and what will be the impact if we install .

Answer (score 1):

Try with `rar e file.rar` instead.